# disable windows error recovery

Tags: windows-7, boot

Can the windows error recovery screen, that appears after boot or shutdown failures be disabled completely?

I have tried `bcdedit /set {current} bootstatuspolicy ignoreallfailures`, but the error recovery screen still appears if the power is cut during boot and shutdown.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to disable this?

Comment: The installations runs as black box and has start as normal after power failure and such. No human intervention after it leaves my desk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also try editing the registry setting.

Clear the value in:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Control \ Session Manager \ BootExecute

(from a related question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/176937/windows-7-startup-repair-disjoining-system-from-domain) - we're STILL trying to find a way to automate this)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you run as administrator.

After running the command:

```
bcdedit/set {current} bootstatuspolicy ignoreallfailures
```

make sure you go to Start > Restart. This will finish the process. DO NOT just unplug to test that it worked - restart then test.